# How to add custom css file in YT Framework Joomla Template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I am using YT Framework on Joomla2.5, I want to add new css file fot the template SJ+, but I could not find any documentation for the framework.

I have general understanding that, as the css will be builded every time I install any component or module, so in order to implement our custom css, I need to add my css in a specific file, but I am unable to find where to keep that file and with what name.

I have tried by adding a "custom.css" file in template's css folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking deeper into each of the css file I came to solution for loading of custom css for YT Framework templates.
Keep your custom css in a file named "your_css.css" file under the css folder of your template, this is the functionality of the YT frame work that after loading all the css files required by the template, it loads this css file at the end so that all the default and dynamic css will be overloaded with all the stylings you have written in your_css.css file

Answer (score 0):

For any template if you need to add your custome css code you need to first find index.php file in your template directory,

If you found html code in index.php then add your css code to index file using  tag. or add

if you do not found html code in index.php file then you need to find component.php file in template root folder.

and follow the same thing as for index.php

Comment: for YT framework this will works:
http://www.yootheme.com/themes/documentation/legacy-warp-55/add-custom-css-and-javascript-files

Comment: YT Frame work is not The yoo theme frame work,yoo theme framework is called,Wrap frame work.

Comment: @pepa wega ,why is it you didn't check my Idea,I have checked and it's working,can you put the link to the template.thanks